# How to read command line argument to qmake in qmake.conf

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I would like to read command line argument I pass to qmake in .qmake.conf
but looks like I cannot figure out how.

here is my qmake line:

```
qmake.exe d:\Project\my.pro -r -spec qnx-armle-v7-qcc "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=declarative_debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug" "INSTALL_PREFIX=d:/tmp123"
```

I would like to read INSTALL_PREFIX in qmake.conf, but

message($${INSTALL_PREFIX}) is empty

in same time in my.pro file

message($${INSTALL_PREFIX}) produces "d:/tmp123"

This is very puzzling!! Please help

QT 5.3.1
QT Creator 3.1.2
Windows 7 PRO 64bit

Comment: Why don't you put all these variables into the my.pro file?

Comment: @vahancho becasue I have 17 pro files in various loosly related subprojects